# Which meta_query and post_content blend is better in WP_Query, performance wise?

Tags: wp-query

I need to `WP_Query` for posts which:

- either have a postmeta 'answer' set to 'yes', and whatever `post_content`;
- or have 'answer' set to 'no' but only if `post_content` is empty.

So in an ideal world where performance is not an issue and where you can query both for a postmeta and `post_content`, the args would look something like this:

```
$args = array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
   'meta_query' => array(
      'key' => 'answer',
      'compare' => '=',
      'value' => 'yes'
   ),
   array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      'meta_query' => array(
         'key' => 'answer',
         'compare' => '=',
         'value' => 'no'
      ),
      array(
         'key' => 'post_content',
         'compare' => '=',
         'value' => ''
      )
   )
);
```

Now, we're not in that ideal world and as far as I know I can't check the `post_content` in the `WP_Query` in the first place, so my answer is: **which way is better to assign a `post_content` related `WP_Query`-able value to a post, performance wise**?

1. to programmatically add or remove a **postmeta** like 'has_content' set to 1 or 0 to the post each time it's created/updated, so I can just do a `meta_query`;
2. to programmatically add or remove a **tag** like 'has_content' set to 1 or 0 to the post each time it's created/updated (and check for it with `tag__in` in `WP_Query`);
3. to programmatically add or remove a custom hidden **taxonomy** like 'has_content' set to 1 or 0 to the post each time it's created/updated (and check for it with a `tax_query` in `WP_Query`);
4. none of the above.

I tend to exclude point 1 because I've read about `meta_query`'s performance issues, but I am not sure about 2-3-4.

Thanks a lot if you can help!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need `tag__in` for option 2? You're not searching for multiple values, only your 1 or 0. In which case, options 2 and 3 amount to the same thing behind the scenes: a taxonomy query. This way would likely be the most performant, but that said, if you don't want to mess the taxonomies, [you can check for empty post content with a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395115/wp-query-check-if-the-post-content-is-empty).

Comment: You're right pointing out about options 2 and 3, I'll probably go with a tax_query. My concern about [the WHERE filter you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395115/wp-query-check-if-the-post-content-is-empty) is that it affects the whole query, whereas I need to apply the post_content clause (thus the WHERE filter, if I used it) only in 1 out of the 2 scenarios of the meta_query. Correct me if I'm wrong.